# Attempting to convert a value into 2s complement in C

Tags: c

I am writing an emulator in C and I want to make the constantValuable , which is 65530 (0xFFFA) be the two's complement variable of 5 however I cannot seem to get it quite right. Below is the example of the if statement where I would like this to be done.

```
if(opCodeType == 4)
            {
                if(registers[rsVariable] == registers[rtVariable])
                {
                    int twosVariable = ~(constantVariable) + 1;
                    printf("%d", twosVariable);
                    pc = pc + (twosVariable*4);
                }
            }
```

I can't seem to understand why this does not work.

Comment: What *do* you get? For debugging, can you print the hexadecimal value of `constantVariable` and `twosVariable `?

Comment: The two's complement of `5` isn't `0xFFFA` but `0xFFFB`.

Comment: I get -65531 for twosVariable, and 65530 for constantVariable.

Comment: That's because your `int `is 32-bit not 16 bit.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `-6`?

Comment: I don't get `-65531` and `65530`, I get `-65530` and `65530` with your code. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input and the output, and the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed 2's complement is such that the complement to your number `n` (which algebraically is `-n`) is derived by *reflecting* the bit pattern of `n` then adding 1 to that number. Note that in a 2's complement scheme, -1 has all its bits set to 1.

The problem with reflecting the bit pattern using `~` is that it can cause unwanted type promotion which ruins the result.

One solution is to mask the the result of `~`, another is to cast the result. Of course, on a 2's complement platform, you can write simply `-n`, taking care to ensure that `n` is not already the smallest possible negative.